# Why is the value of datetime-local format changing to UTC instead of T?

Tags: php

I am trying to get the value of the `datetime-local` type of input which is `2020-09-20 16:03:00` from the database. To show this value in the input, I need the format `Y-m-dTH:m` so that the value with become `2020-09-20T16:03:00` but instead of that, the `T` will become `UTC` so the input won't show the value because it is the wrong format.

```
<input type="datetime-local" value="{{ date('Y-m-dTH:m', strtotime($document->date_received)) }}">
```

Thanks to this link, I got the right format https://stackoverflow.com/a/49004716/7074729

Comment: T is the character for timezone in PHP,  you need to escape it i.e. use `\T` like [this sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a6f206f29e18a4484a367d1f4bdb6bb022ddbf92)

Comment: @apokryfos you are right. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add \ before the T `Y-m-dTH:m` into `Y-m-d\TH:m`

Correct answer by [apokryfos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/487813/apokryfos) in the comment section